# How to string brackets within a dataframe column heading?

Tags: python, string, dataframe, anova, patsy

My excel sheet has **Time(s)** as a heading.

when I input it into one of my codes in python for two-way anova analysis like so:

```
 F1_para1 = 'ROI'
 F2_para2 = 'Drug'
 value = 'Time(s)'
   
 df['comb'] = df[F1_para1].map(str) + "+" + df[F2_para2].map(str) #group for pairwise comparison
 mod = ols(value+'~'+F1_para1+'+'+F2_para2+'+'+F1_para1+'*'+F2_para2, data = df).fit()
 aov = anova_lm(mod, type=2)
```

I get this error message

```
 PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'Time' is not defined
    Time(s)~ROI+Drug+ROI*Drug
    ^^^^^^^
```

Was thinking it has something to do with **(s)** as it works fine with dataframe headings without brackets. Is there a way around this?

**Current Troubleshooting attempts**

- I have tried doubling the brackets to troubleshoot it but I get this as an error:

> ```
> PatsyError: Error evaluating factor: NameError: name 'Time' is not defined
>
> Time((s))~ROI+Drug+ROI*Drug
> ^^^^^^^^^
> ```

- I have also tried using str(Time(s))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this here in case someone needs help

Use `Q("Time(s)")` to overcome the issue